# When I render something, there's an indent in the model, but when It's not rendered there is no indent. how do I fix this?

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]

[image]

I just can't find what's wrong

[image]

Here's the file of it, if that can help with it

Comment: Neither can we from two screenshots. You will have to addd more information to your question.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos what type of information would you need? because I don't know what I would need to look for, to give information. Sorry

Comment: Everything, object topology, modifiers, materials, textures, screenshots.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with your topology. Also, if you want to stay low-poly without any *Subdivision Surface*, you have to use the *Auto Smooth*, otherwise the twisted planes of your object will always create artifacts.

First of all, you have unwanted faces. If you go in *Edit* / *Face Select* mode, you can see some faces squeezed between faces. It has nothing to do with the problem you're talking about but anyway you need to correct that because it's not good to keep this kind of topology. It must have been created by some accidental extrusions. So select all your vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> and click <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Double*, it will merge all overlayed vertices and remove all these unwanted faces. It's not the only problem of your topology but it's the most obvious.

[image]

Now, about your problem: Your object is made of several planes that are not flat but twisted like chips, so, as you didn't smooth your object with *Smooth Shading* and *Subdivision Surface* modifier, which would have helped to smooth these surfaces, they do appear like triangles and not like planes.

If you want to avoid these artifacts you have several solutions, you can either:

- Use the *Smooth Shading* (in the 3D view *Tool* panel displayed with <kbd>T</kbd> > *Tools* tab > *Edit* > *Shading*). But it will give non very aesthetic gradients as your object doesn't have enough polygons.
- Keep this *Smooth Shading* but add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier so that your object has virtually more polygons.

But these solutions are interesting only if you want to give your object a smooth and high-poly appearance. If you want to keep it low-poly you should use this trick:

- Keep your object *Flat* and with no *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Go to the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Normals* and enable *Auto Smooth*. The *Auto Smooth* option is supposed to determine the angle below which the *Smooth Shading* will happen, but in *Flat Shading* it will also make your twisted plane look flat and uniform.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go into the depths of moonbots lesson, you can fix your model with 2 clicks in this case.

[image]